# bash alias with different caller

Tags: node.js, bash

Is there a way to set up an alias such that a file could be called with different binary.

e.g.

```
node path-to-some-file
nodemon path-to-some-file
pm2 path-to-some-file
```

where `path-to-some-file` is like `/mnt/hgfs/start.js`

Answer (score 3):

If we ignore the keyword *alias*, which has very specific meaning in bash, we can consider other solutions.  Symbolic links can provide a useful tool for what you are trying to do.  Consider this:

```
ln -s /mnt/hgfs/start.js ~/start.js
```

Now you can access your symbolic link like this:

```
node ~/start.js
nodemon ~/start.js
pm2 ~/start.js
```

Alternatively, you can just set an environment variable to the file name:

```
START=/mnt/hgfs/start.js
```

And access the file like this:

```
node $START
nodemon $START
pm2 $START
```

Setting the environment in your .bashrc will make the "alias" available to all your interactive shells.

You may also consider creating an environment variable or symbolic link to the directory if you have a lot of files in that directory.  This way, you have a short cut for the directory.

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty ugly, but I usually assign an alias with an echo command:

```
$ alias test_script="echo /tmp/test.js"
$ node $(test_script)
$ vim $(test_script)
```

Comment: Why would you use an alias in this situation instead of a simple variable? `test_script=/tmp/test.js; node "$test_script"`?

Comment: Using variables is way better than an alias for sure. I got the alias workaround recently for solving a problem with some bash functions grepping paths, it was a mess.

Comment: You might want to ask about your original problem, then. I can't even picture a problem where this kind of unnecessary alias expansion is a legitimate solution.